# Xampp Access violation at address 005ABEFFE

Tags: xampp

I have an issue with my XAMPP Control Pannel.

Each time I run my XAMPP Control Pannel, it shuts down, with these errors :

[image: XAMPP Control Pannel log]

This is what the application error window show me :

```
  Exception EAccessViolation in module xampp-control.exe at 001ABEFFE.
  Access violation at address 005ABEFFE in module 'xampp-controle.exe'.
  Read of address 00000042.
```

And this is the details of the crash :

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: xampp-control.exe
  Application Version:  3.1.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    505b977e
  Fault Module Name:    xampp-control.exe
  Fault Module Version: 3.1.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   505b977e
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 001abefe
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1036
  Additional Information 1: 85f1
  Additional Information 2: 85f130a438e7576b1a9e31c22e4b9f42
  Additional Information 3: 5349
  Additional Information 4: 53499a809c3ee8ed8ef93e12b24b146b

  Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

  If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Can you explain me how to fix it please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you need to make sure that services is not disabled by doing this :

1. Open Run Command (Windows + R)
2. type `services.msc`
3. Find apache service
4. Check startup type on the right column

To change startup type, please do following step :

1. Right click on services that you want to change startup type
2. Find properties
3. Change startup type either to manual or automatic

Answer (score 77):

First, your user must have administrator permission.

Second, install Xampp outside of "**program files**", preferably install in `C:\xampp` (It usually comes with this by default).

Third, after installation (Before running Xampp), go to the `C:\xampp` directory, look for `xampp-control.exe`, right click on it, go to "**properties**" go to the "**compatibility**" tab and then check the "**run as administrator**" option.

Comment: Now the error message "Error: Cannot create file "C:\xampp\xampp-control.ini". Access is denied." makes sense.

Answer (score 47):

This error is showing you due to `Xampp-control.exe` doesn't have permission to write on the file named `xampp-control.ini`. Follow below steps to get rid of this:

- Go to Xampp directory.
- Search for file `xampp-control.ini`.
- Go to properties of that file.
- Under security tab Select users Everyone.
- Edit permissions and provide full control.
- And Apply

Comment: Fantastic answer! thanks for saving my life!

Comment: The perfect answer. You don't even need to provide full control. Checking the "Write" permission will do it.

Comment: Simple & perfect answer. Worked for me!

Comment: Anyone know whats the reasons why this suddenly caused? Previosly working fine

Comment: I saw alot of videos which suggested run as administrator, which i didn't like. But this answer is above all. Perfect

Answer (score 25):

**1st try this option.**

- Goto Xampp folder in **c:/xampp**
- search for **xampp.control.ini**
- right click on xampp.control.ini & click on properties.
- Goto security select everyone & click on Edit button
- In permissions for everyone select 1st option(**Full control**)
- check all options are selected or not and then click on Apply & then OK.

This will solve you problem.

**Note: Above solution works only when you logged in with Admin account.**

Comment: Came here for another problem, this helped me!! My problem was, when I right-clicked the XAMPP icon and closed it, the access violation appeared.

Comment: I believe it is "xampp-control.ini" not "xampp.control.ini"

Comment: Awesome, finally a solution for that "disgusting" problem which was really annoying.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had this problem for a while and it was really annoying, finally got around fixing it.

Answer (score 8):

To correct the error :

1. Go to **xampp** directory (The location can be C:\xampp )
2. look for xampp-control application file ( i.e file with icon and .exe extension )
3. right click on xampp-control.exe file and click **Properties** option
4. Now, select **compatibility** among the tabs and check the checkbox for "**Run this program as an administrator**"
5. Finally, click Apply and Ok.

Here, the problem is solved. Try to start and quit xampp, it will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2yZG.png)

This error is showing you due to **Xampp-control.exe** haven't permission to write on the file named **"xampp-control.ini"**.
So, follow below steps to get rid of this:

1. Go to Xampp directory.
2. Search for file **xampp-control.ini**.
3. Go to properties of that file.
4. Under security tab Select users **Everyone**.
5. Edit permissions & provide full control.
6. And Apply.
   [xampp-control.ini with full control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8tQp.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a command prompt (Start > Run > cmd)
2. run "sc delete Apache2.4"
3. At the control-p of XAMPP - go to config of Apache then click Apache and chose the file name Apache installservice .
   4- try now

Answer (score 1):

Following solution worked for me,

Earlier I used to save logs to the following path, but in my recent changes I forgot to update same path in my **httpd-vhosts.conf**

ErrorLog "**D:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/logs/mysite.com-error.log**"

CustomLog "**D:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/logs/mysite.com-access.log**" common

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/mysite"
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    ErrorLog "D:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/logs/mysite.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "D:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/logs/mysite.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

As soon as I updated correct path, all XAMPP processes started working without any error...